# JSONB nulls and order by

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, jsonb

It seems that order by with nulls doesn't really work for jsonb?

if I have many rows in a table that look like this:

```
key   | cae1f6e1-8c1b-4fec-9002-7fd878e0dc06
value | {"id": "cae1f6e1-8c1b-4fec-9002-7fd878e0dc06",
         "debit-amount": 207853501,
         "credit-amount": null}
```

and when I run query like this:

```
select value->'debit-amount' deb from balance_table
  order by deb asc
  nulls last 
  limit 20;
```

it still shows only nulls

Answer (score 4):

You can cast `'null'::jsonb` to `null` with [`nullif()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF):

```
select nullif(value->'debit-amount', 'null') deb 
from balance_table
order by deb asc nulls last 
limit 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is in the following part:

```
order by deb asc
nulls last 
limit 20;
```

You would assume that this sorts all rows in a way that the ones that have `null` for `debit-amount` will end up in the end, so that when to do limit 20 you will probably see only non null ones. There is only one issue, the jsonb `null` is not the same as the sql `null`.

For example, suppose that a particular row has a `value` with `"debit-amount": null`. Then `value->'debit-amount'` will return a jsonb `null`, which will get sorted to the top, because that's how the order in jsonb works. In other words, you'll never get a sql `null` (unless of course the whole `value` is sql `null`), so the `nulls last` is pointless here.

You probably want something like that:

```
select value->'debit-amount' deb
from balance_table
order by ((value->'debit-amount')='null'::jsonb)::integer, deb asc
limit 20;
```

The expression `((value->'debit-amount')='null'::jsonb)::integer` will convert all (jsonb) `null`s for `debit-amount` to 1 and will return 0 otherwise. This will push all (jsonb) `null`s to the end.

Comment: erghhr... I actually need to make null values to be last when sorted in ascending order. I can't do when<>null (I think) because when debit-amount is null credit is always something (and vice versa) I'm guessing `'null'::jsonb` is not the same as postgres's native `null` that's why `nulls last|first` won't work

Comment: @Agzam I updated my answer so as not to exclude the (jsonb) null, but instead have them sorted to the end.